# Why are these special device file reads a minimum of PAGE SIZE bytes?

Tags: linux, kernel

I am coding my 2nd kernel module ever. I am attempting to provide user-space access to a firmware core, as a demo. The demo is under petalinux (an embedded OS specifically tailored to Zynq or Microblaze). I added virtual file system hooks to go between user space and the kernel module, and it seems to work, both on read and write. The only hiccup is that, somewhere between my user application and my kernel module, the OS balloons the size of my request up to PAGE SIZE (4096).

A co-worker commented that I might be mounting the module as a block device rather than a character device. This makes a lot of sense. Someone upstream of my module is certainly caching my results (which, if my understanding of block drivers is accurate, would make perfect sense for, say, the hard drive), but we're tied to a volatile device, so this isn't appropriate. But all the diagnostics I've been able to find suggest that it is mounted as a character device...

```
mknod /dev/myModule **c** (Dynamically specified Major Number) (Zero)
ls -la /dev/myModule
   **c**rw-r--r--     1   root    root 252, -    Jan 1 01:05 myModule
```

Here is the module source I am using to register the virtual file IO hooks.....

```
alloc_chrdev_region (&moduleMajorNumber, 0, 1, "moduleLayerCDMA");
register_chrdev_region  (&moduleMajorNumber,    1, "moduleLayerCDMA");    
cdevP = cdev_alloc();
cdevP->ops = &moduleLayerCDMA_fileOperations;
cdevP->owner = THIS_MODULE;
cdev_add(cdevP, moduleMajorNumber, 1);
```

Any clues?

Comment: Are you using something like `fread()` to read from the device in your user application?

Comment: I am. And your intuition is right, that is the problem; using dd from the command line gets rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the fact that the standard C library buffered I/O routines (`fopen`, `fclose`, `fread`, `fgetch` & their friends) keep a user-space buffer for every opened file/device, and when your program tries to read from that file/device, the library routines try to do read-ahead, to prepare for later read calls, to increase the efficiency of the I/O. Similarly, writes with `fwrite` go through a write buffer, and only get flushed to the system with a system call when the buffer gets full or when closing the file/device or explicitly doing `fflush`.

There are two ways to solve the issue:

- The easier might be to simply convert your user-space program to use non-buffered I/O (`open`, `close`, `read`, `write` & their friends), these are simply making the corresponding system call on a 1:1 basis.
- Or handle the problem in your kernel module: disregard the number of bytes asked in a `read` if it is more than what you'd like to return in a single system call. You can look at that value as the length of the buffer provided by the caller, and you don't neccessarily have to fill it up completely. Of course, in the return value, you have to indicate how many bytes were actually read.